# Group by condition on elements of column

Tags: r

I have the following data.

```
> new
# A tibble: 950 x 3
# Groups:   birthday_year [91]
   birthday_year product       count
           <dbl> <chr>         <int>
 1          1931 A                 2
 2          1932 A                 1
 3          1938 B                 1
 4          1939 B                 1
 5          1942 A                 1
 6          1957 A                 5
 7          1960 A                 1
 8          1963 A                 2
 9          1967 A                 2
10          1969 B                 5
# ... with 940 more rows
```

I want to group by the decade (of the year in the birthday_year column) (i.e. by the elements of the first column such that the first three digits are the same) and the product column. So the new data would look like this:

```
> new
# A tibble: 950 x 3
# Groups:   birthday_year [91]
          decade product       count
           <dbl> <chr>         <int>
 1          1930 A                 3
 2          1930 B                 2
 3          1940 A                 1
 4          1940 B                 0
 5          1950 A                 1
 6          1950 A                 0
 7          1960 A                 8
 8          1960 A                 5
# ... with xxx more rows
```

Do you guys have any idea how to proceed? thanks in advance

Comment: I would first create the column `decade` and the group by it with `dplyr::group_by`. If you have `x <- 1930:1990` try this and see what you get `x - (x %% 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(decade = birthday_year - birthday_year%%10) %>% select(-birthday_year) %>% 
group_by(decade, product) %>% summarise(count = sum(count)) %>% complete(decade, product = c('A','B'), fill = list(count = 0))
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'decade' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   decade [4]
  decade product count
   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1   1930 A           3
2   1930 B           2
3   1940 A           1
4   1940 B           0
5   1950 A           5
6   1950 B           0
7   1960 A           5
8   1960 B           5
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   birthday_year product count
           <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
 1          1931 A           2
 2          1932 A           1
 3          1938 B           1
 4          1939 B           1
 5          1942 A           1
 6          1957 A           5
 7          1960 A           1
 8          1963 A           2
 9          1967 A           2
10          1969 B           5
```